# Degree of Profanity in a Sentence

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

Given a comment or a sentence and a list of profane words, How do I write a program to print the degree of profanity in that sentence?

Comment: fast.ai has neural networks that are already good with NLP (understanding text). You could train one of those models to categorize text as being profane or not.

Comment: can you provide me link to the resources?

Comment: https://github.com/fastai/fastai

Comment: How do you measure "degree of profanity"?

Comment: some words maybe more profane than other words.. But again that depends on person to person how we define profanity. so wanted to get different views, what can be considered as degree of profanity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach it is to split the sentence into tokens and count the number of tokens that are profanities.

```
import re

def tokenize(text): 
    return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

profane_tokens = {"nerfherder"}

sentence = "Why you stuck-up, half-witted, scruffy-looking nerfherder!"

tokens = tokenize(sentence)

# Rate: number of occurrences normalized by total number
degree_of_profanity = sum(1 for t in tokens if t in profane) / len(tokens)
```

This code will not handle multiple tokens and many profanities are multiple tokens.

Comment: thanks.. 
will try to make the code more robust..

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably find pointers in the literature searching for "offensive text detection". There are many variants/overlaps with related tasks such as detecting bullying. There are probably also annotated datasets around, in case you want to use these as training data.

Comment: yeah sure.. 
I will have a look.
But, I am confused on what metrics to consider to calculate the degree of the offensive text or profanity. Most searches resulted in finding if the text is offensive or not offensive not the degree of profanity. 
can you share any resources.

Comment: @naman afaik there's no such thing in general. different people don't agree about what is a profanity or not, let alone how offensive a particular instance is. There's a very high level of subjectivity and cultural background involved. Additionally in some contexts people use a variety of techniques to obfuscate profanities, e.g. "s.h.1.t". I don't know any resources sorry, the only one I know of is not freely available. I would try to search for competitions/shared tasks, for instance in the SemEval or CLEF series.

Comment: thanks.. the definition of profanity depends on what we define profanity as.